# how can i add a zoom effect for viewing my table text details

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table and it contains dynamic details,now i wish to add a zoom effect for viewing each table cells details(text). how can i make it possible

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>head1</th>
<th>head2</th>
<th>head3</th>
<th>head4</th>
</tr>
<td>details1</td>
<td>details1</td>
<td>details1</td>
<td>details1</td>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>details2</td>
<td>details2</td>
<td>details2</td>
<td>details2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>details3</td>
<td>details3</td>
<td>details3</td>
<td>details3</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use transition effect if you want to achieve it using css alone.

Example:

```
table td:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}
```

If you want to use jquery then you can use any of jquery ui property such as easin , easout etc etc..

Comment: That method is good. but not using hover effect . need another method

Comment: like what kind of effect??

Comment: like image zoom effect method

Comment: Check this and use any one of them http://www.webdesignrazzi.com/2014/jquery-zoom-effect-plugins/